# Fast autocomplete from in-memory collection (.NET)

Tags: c#, linq, search

I have this text input field on a web page. User types in item names for purchase. I'd like to provide a dropdown with possible names, based on letters typed so far.

Question is how to implement the search on the server (ASP.NET MVC). I'll probably load the whole collection of item names (there are over 100 000) in a static variable on app start. How should I implement efficient search for names starting with given one or more characters?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the collection by name, then write a modified binary search that returns a range of items.

However, I would recommend first trying a simple sequential search and seeing how it behaves under load.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll probably load the whole
>   collection of item names (there are
>   over 100 000) in a static variable on
>   app start. How should I implement
>   efficient search for names starting
>   with given one or more characters?

By NOT (!) loading them into a static variable. Hit the db server on every request with a "top 101" clause. Finished.

Comment: TomTom, really? That page is under heavy load at times. The autocomplete must be instant. Hitting the DB for read-only data is against all best practices I've heard. There must be a reason ppl are using Memcached and Velocity.

Comment: Yes, really. or precache results (i.e. entry string, results returned), which can be done via IIS output cache. Do NOT reimplement the database. If oyu need more db servers get them. Programming will cost you more.